# How to remove the gap in the SidebarMenu in Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

Does anyone know please how to remove the gap in the front of the SidebarMenu in Codename One?

[image: the problem's picture]

Comment: Looks like a margin and/or padding issue

Comment: no it's not i already did that..

Comment: How about the image itself... size, transparent areas?

Answer (score 0):

Define the UIID `StatusBarSideMenu` and define it's padding to 0.

It's there to prevent iOS devices from drawing on top of the clock/battery signs.